# How do I download a COMPLETE Wikia database?

Tags: download, wikia

I have been trying to download Wikias databases (for example the Marvel Wikia) with the [official method](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Special:Statistics) (as mentioned in this [similar question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/41233/how-to-download-a-wikia)) but when I download the XML file it only contains about 10% of the articles and info.

Even more strange, the full one (with history) is even a lost smaller than the only current articles one.

Is that common? This happened to me in any Wikia I have tried.

Is there any other method to download all articles from the Wikia in XML format?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download a Wikia?](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/41233/how-to-download-a-wikia)

Comment: no, it is not, I am asking for an alternative method to that one... As it fails in many cases...

Answer (score 1):

I have contacted Wikia support service and they said it was a bug. They are supposedly fixing it now.